# Get all parent products with "instock" stock status in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce I have the following SQL query to select parent products. I would like to select only "in-stock" product.

This is My actual SQL query:

```
$query=$db->query("select * from wp_posts 
  where post_parent='0' and post_type='product'  and post_status='publish' 
  group by ID 
  limit 10");
```

How can I Select only "in-stock" parent products *(but not all of them)*?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge updated as requested

Comment: i don't see any appreciable  .. sample of data  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to get only parent products with a stock status like "instock":
:

```
global $wpdb;

// The SQL query
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT p.*, pm.meta_value as stock_status
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND p.post_parent = '0'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value LIKE 'instock' 
    GROUP BY p.ID
" );

// Testing output (objects array)
echo '<pre>'; print_r($results); echo '</pre>';
```

Tested and works.

---

To get only the product IDs:

```
global $wpdb;

// The SQL query
$results = $wpdb->get_col( "
    SELECT p.ID
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND p.post_parent = '0'
    AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_stock_status'
    AND pm.meta_value LIKE 'instock' 
" );

// Testing output (array of IDs)
echo '<pre>'; print_r($results); echo '</pre>';
```